# Flutter rounded rectangle border with different colours for each side

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to re-create a button I made with React Native that had different colours for each side giving it a kind of chiseled effect, a bit like Photoshop bevel and emboss, but also with rounded corners. At the moment I have a container outside the button which has the border on it, and inside I'm using `RawMaterialButton`. The code for the container is like this:

```
Container(
    BoxDecoration(
    border: Border(
    left: BorderSide(
    color: Colors.black,
    width: 1.0,
    ),
    top: BorderSide(
    color: Colors.black,
    width: 1.0,
     ),
    ),
   ),
  )
```

How can I make the corners for this border/container rounded?

Like this but with rounded corners:

[image]

Comment: ca you please post an expected result image

Comment: @Manoj Perumarath Ok posted an image. Like that but with rounded corners.

Comment: At the moment, I don't think this is possible. You can have a box decoration but to be able to set the border radius, the border needs to be uniform on all sides. Which means you can't have different colors or border stroke widths

Comment: @Ajil O. Yes that's what I feared. `BorderSide` doesn't seem to accept any kind of radius setting whatsoever. It's a shame because that button in React Native with a chiseled look and rounded corners looked really great.

Comment: @Hasen You should still be able to do it using CustomPainter.

Comment: @Ajil O I'm guessing it's not easy. I'm making my first app with Flutter so not really that familiar with it. If there is a way that isn't really troublesome then please post an answer. If it's really not simple then maybe just leave it as being 'not possible'.

Comment: @Hasen It's not really hard. As long as you want the width to be uniform it's easy for me to create an implementation for this. But if the stroke widths are different for different sides then I would need more time.

Comment: @Ajil O The border widths would be the same, yes, just each side would be a different colour. The rounded radius would also be the same all around it too.

Comment: Quick solution could be to use an image then use centerslice so that it behaves like a 9patch png

Comment: @F-1 Obviously using an image would be completely different and incredibly easy. I built the app originally a few years back in React Native and I was able to make it look really great with zero images for all the different buttons, which made for a very small app. I'm now trying to do the same with Flutter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a 100% working solution. I just wrote some Path functions to draw all the sides using `CustomPainter`.

**RoundedChiseledBorder**

```dart
class RoundedChiseledBorder extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;

  final Color leftBorderColor;
  final Color rightBorderColor;
  final Color bottomBorderColor;
  final Color topBorderColor;

  final double borderRadius;
  final double borderWidth;

  RoundedChiseledBorder({
    @required this.child,
    this.borderRadius = 1,
    this.borderWidth = 2,
    this.bottomBorderColor = Colors.black,
    this.topBorderColor = Colors.black,
    this.rightBorderColor = Colors.black,
    this.leftBorderColor = Colors.black,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Positioned.fill(
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: RoundedBorderPainter(
              radius: borderRadius,
              strokeWidth: borderWidth,
              bottomBorderColor: bottomBorderColor,
              leftBorderColor: leftBorderColor,
              rightBorderColor: rightBorderColor,
              topBorderColor: topBorderColor,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        child,
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**RoundedBorderPainterBorder**

```dart
import 'package:vector_math/vector_math.dart' as vm;

class RoundedBorderPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Color leftBorderColor;
  final Color rightBorderColor;
  final Color bottomBorderColor;
  final Color topBorderColor;
  final double strokeWidth;
  final StrokeCap strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;
  double radius;

  Size size;

  RoundedBorderPainter({
    this.leftBorderColor = Colors.black,
    this.rightBorderColor = Colors.black,
    this.topBorderColor = Colors.black,
    this.bottomBorderColor = Colors.black,
    this.strokeWidth = 2,
    this.radius = 1,
  }) {
    if (radius <= 1) this.radius = 1;
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    radius = size.shortestSide / 2 < radius ? size.shortestSide / 2 : radius;
    this.size = size;
    Paint topPaint = Paint()
      ..color = topBorderColor
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
      ..strokeCap = strokeCap
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    Paint rightPaint = Paint()
      ..color = rightBorderColor
      ..strokeCap = strokeCap
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    Paint bottomPaint = Paint()
      ..color = bottomBorderColor
      ..strokeCap = strokeCap
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    Paint leftPaint = Paint()
      ..strokeCap = strokeCap
      ..color = leftBorderColor
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    canvas.drawPath(getPath1(), topPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(getPath2(), rightPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(getPath3(), bottomPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(getPath4(), leftPaint);
  }

  Path getPath1() {
    return Path()
      ..addPath(getTopLeftPath2(), Offset(0, 0))
      ..addPath(getTopPath(), Offset(0, 0))
      ..addPath(getTopRightPath1(), Offset(0, 0));
  }

  Path getPath2() {
    return Path()
      ..addPath(getTopRightPath2(), Offset(0, 0))
      ..addPath(getRightPath(), Offset(0, 0))
      ..addPath(getBottomRightPath1(), Offset(0, 0));
  }

  Path getPath3() {
    return Path()
      ..addPath(getBottomRightPath2(), Offset(0, 0))
      ..addPath(getBottomPath(), Offset(0, 0))
      ..addPath(getBottomLeftPath1(), Offset(0, 0));
  }

  Path getPath4() {
    return Path()
      ..addPath(getBottomLeftPath2(), Offset(0, 0))
      ..addPath(getLeftPath(), Offset(0, 0))
      ..addPath(getTopLeftPath1(), Offset(0, 0));
  }

  Path getTopPath() {
    return Path()
      ..moveTo(0 + radius, 0)
      ..lineTo(size.width - radius, 0);
  }

  Path getRightPath() {
    return Path()
      ..moveTo(size.width, 0 + radius)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height - radius);
  }

  Path getBottomPath() {
    return Path()
      ..moveTo(size.width - radius, size.height)
      ..lineTo(0 + radius, size.height);
  }

  Path getLeftPath() {
    return Path()
      ..moveTo(0, size.height - radius)
      ..lineTo(0, 0 + radius);
  }

  Path getTopRightPath1() {
    return Path()
      ..addArc(
        Rect.fromLTWH(size.width - (radius * 2), 0, radius * 2, radius * 2),
        vm.radians(-45),
        vm.radians(-45),
      );
  }

  Path getTopRightPath2() {
    return Path()
      ..addArc(
        Rect.fromLTWH(size.width - (radius * 2), 0, radius * 2, radius * 2),
        vm.radians(0),
        vm.radians(-45),
      );
  }

  Path getBottomRightPath1() {
    return Path()
      ..addArc(
        Rect.fromLTWH(size.width - (radius * 2), size.height - (radius * 2), radius * 2, radius * 2),
        vm.radians(45),
        vm.radians(-45),
      );
  }

  Path getBottomRightPath2() {
    return Path()
      ..addArc(
        Rect.fromLTWH(size.width - (radius * 2), size.height - (radius * 2), radius * 2, radius * 2),
        vm.radians(90),
        vm.radians(-45),
      );
  }

  Path getBottomLeftPath1() {
    return Path()
      ..addArc(
        Rect.fromLTWH(0, size.height - (radius * 2), radius * 2, radius * 2),
        vm.radians(135),
        vm.radians(-45),
      );
  }

  Path getBottomLeftPath2() {
    return Path()
      ..addArc(
        Rect.fromLTWH(0, size.height - (radius * 2), radius * 2, radius * 2),
        vm.radians(180),
        vm.radians(-45),
      );
  }

  Path getTopLeftPath1() {
    return Path()
      ..addArc(
        Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, radius * 2, radius * 2),
        vm.radians(225),
        vm.radians(-45),
      );
  }

  Path getTopLeftPath2() {
    return Path()
      ..addArc(
        Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, radius * 2, radius * 2),
        vm.radians(270),
        vm.radians(-45),
      );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

**USAGE**

To use it just call

```dart
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RoundedChiseledBorder(
          borderRadius: 10,
          borderWidth: 4,
          bottomBorderColor: Colors.red,
          leftBorderColor: Colors.black,
          rightBorderColor: Colors.amber,
          topBorderColor: Colors.green,
          child: Container(
            height: 30,
            width: 300,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text('Hello'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow that is SO long. All because they forgot to add a border radius option to `BorderSide`. Anyway I'll try it out and see how it works.

Comment: To be fair, it can be simplified and the code can be made much shorter. I'll build this into a package and push it to pub when I have time.

Comment: Yeah sounds great. It's certainly useful to have this option in Flutter. :)

Comment: Not sure if anyone can answer my other Flutter button question here if you want to have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56930636/flutter-button-with-custom-shape-triangle

Comment: Trying it now but getting `vm` is undefined in `RoundedBorderPainter`?

Comment: Add `import 'package:vector_math/vector_math.dart' as vm;` to the top

Comment: Not sure if this is gonna work for me because I was originally using `Container` which has all kinds of parameters that your new `RoundedChiseledBorder` doesn't have like `gradient`, `margin`, 'boxShadow' etc.

Comment: I am aware that this is not an out of the box solution. You could wrap this widget inside anothe container and give it `BoxShadows`. You can give a container as a child to this widget and give it gradients. It's more of mix and match now...

Comment: I wrapped the container with the gradients in it with the `RoundedChiseledBorder` so that the body of the button had gradient colour with the chiseled border around it, and then wrapped that in another container to get margins around it.

Answer (score 1):

Ajil's solution looks like the right direction to go. You are right though, it's an amazing amount of work for such a small thing.

Here is my tedious effort, it needs to be simplified to tidy it up but it produces a more accurate representation of your image.

```
class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExampleState createState() {
    return _ExampleState();
  }
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  double height;
  double width;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    const double pi = 3.1415926535897932;
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Some project"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child:
              Container(
                  width: width = 350,
                  height: height = 300,
                  child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                    Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Container(
                          width: 300,
                          height: 300,
                          // color: Colors.red,
                          child: FlatButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                print('button pressed');
                              },
                              child: Text(
                                'BUTTON',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              )),
                        )),
                    Align(
                      //TOP BORDER
                      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.blue[200],
                          border:
                              Border.all(width: 3.0, color: Colors.transparent),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                              topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
                              topRight: Radius.circular(10.0)),
                        ),
                        height: 50,
                        width: width,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Align(
                      //LEFT BORDER
                      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                      child: Container(
                        height: height,
                        width: 30,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.blue[100],
                            border: Border.all(
                                width: 3.0, color: Colors.transparent),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
                                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10.0))),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Align(
                      //RIGHT BORDER
                      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                      child: Container(
                        height: height,
                        width: 15,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.blue[300],
                            border: Border.all(
                                width: 3.0, color: Colors.transparent),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                topRight: Radius.circular(10.0),
                                bottomRight: Radius.circular(10.0))),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Align(
                      //BOTTOM BORDER
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      child: Container(
                        height: 15,
                        width: double.infinity,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            border: Border.all(
                                width: 3.0, color: Colors.transparent),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
                                bottomRight: Radius.circular(10.0))),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Align(
                      //TOPLEFT BORDER
                      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          gradient: SweepGradient(
                              center: FractionalOffset.bottomRight,
                              startAngle: pi * 1.349,
                              endAngle: pi * 1.35,
                              colors: [
                                Colors.blue[100],
                                Colors.blue[200],
                              ]),
                          border:
                              Border.all(width: 3.0, color: Colors.transparent),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                        width: 30,
                        height: 50,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Align(
                        //TOP RIGHT BORDER
                        alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              gradient: SweepGradient(
                                  center: FractionalOffset.topRight,
                                  startAngle: 1.86,
                                  endAngle: 1.87,
                                  colors: [
                                    Colors.blue[300],
                                    Colors.blue[200],
                                  ]),
                              border: Border.all(
                                  width: 3.0, color: Colors.transparent),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                topRight: Radius.circular(10.0),
                              )),
                          width: 15,
                          height: 50,
                        )),
                    Align(
                      //BOTTOMLEFT BORDER
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          gradient: SweepGradient(
                              center: FractionalOffset.bottomLeft,
                              startAngle: 5.8,
                              endAngle: 5.81,
                              colors: [
                                Colors.blue[100],
                                Colors.blue,
                              ]),
                          border:
                              Border.all(width: 3.0, color: Colors.transparent),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                        width: 30,
                        height: 15,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Align(
                        //BOTTOM RIGHT BORDER
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              gradient: SweepGradient(
                                  center: FractionalOffset.bottomRight,
                                  startAngle: 3.99,
                                  endAngle: 4,
                                  colors: [
                                    Colors.blue,
                                    Colors.blue[300],
                                  ]),
                              border: Border.all(
                                  width: 3.0, color: Colors.transparent),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                bottomRight: Radius.circular(10.0),
                                // bottomRight: Radius.circular(10.0)
                              )),
                          width: 15,
                          height: 15,
                        ))
                  ])),
        ));
  }
}
```

[image: How it looks]

Comment: This is pretty good actually. It might be possible to build this better so that the width of the borders, radius, etc can be changed dynamically.

Comment: Agreed, that is what I would do if it were go into production, this was just prototyping a solution.