# How can I implement this type of Button in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, cross-platform, flutter-animation

I tried various other things like FAB Circular menu, but I wasn't able to achieve this outcome. Any help is appreciated.

[This is from an app I saw on the Play Store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDPEO.jpg)

Comment: With that you can create custom triangle: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56930636/flutter-button-with-custom-shape-triangle, after try to use a stack and work on the alignment

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if this is the best way, but I guess you could draw this (e.g. slices of a donut), position them with screen width, sin and cos and then put inkwells on top of them.