# Problem when using BorderRadius in dartpad flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create some examples of using containers in flutter using [DartPad Flutter](https://dartpad.dev/flutter).  Everything worked properly until I used the BorderRadius property where I get these errors :

---

Error: Assertion failed: file:///Users/brettmorgan/Documents/GitHub/dart-services/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/stack_frame.dart:115:12
match != null
"Expected DartError@https://storage.googleapis.com/compilation_artifacts/2.9.0-21.10.beta/dart_sdk.js:5956:7 to match RegExp/^(.+) (\d+):(\d+)\s+(.+)$/."Error: Error: Assertion failed: file:///Users/brettmorgan/Documents/GitHub/dart-services/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/stack_frame.dart:115:12
match != null
"Expected DartError@https://storage.googleapis.com/compilation_artifacts/2.9.0-21.10.beta/dart_sdk.js:5956:7 to match RegExp/^(.+) (\d+):(\d+)\s+(.+)$/."

---

**The source code is :**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color blue = Colors.blue;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: blue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(         
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
  child: Container(
     
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      border: Border(
        top: BorderSide(width: 5.0, color: Color(0xFFFFDFDFFF)),
        left: BorderSide(width: 5.0, color: Color(0xFFFFDFDFFF)),
        right: BorderSide(width: 5.0, color: Color(0xFFFF7F7F88)),
        bottom: BorderSide(width: 5.0, color: Color(0xFFFF7F7F88)),
      ),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(   Radius.circular(10)),
     color: Color(0xFFBFBFCC),
    ),
    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        
    child: Text('The Battle of containers',style : TextStyle(color:Colors.black)),
    width: 200.0,
    height: 100.0,
  ),
);
  }
}
```

So, is BorderRadius not supported in DartPad ?

Comment: After doing research, I found out that we can't use border radius and border together and if we do it will throw an error.
Also found an issues similar to your issue, link : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12583
It contains ideas on how to resolve this. Also similar question is asked before with link: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56928862/flutter-rounded-rectangle-border-with-different-colours-for-each-side

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem was with "**const**" keyword in :
decoration: **const** BoxDecoration(   line.
When I removed it, it worked properly.